# In jq get array based on another array

Tags: arrays, json, bash, iteration, jq

I am using **jq v1.5**. Given the input:

```
{
    "mine": [
        "foo",
        "baz"
    ],
    "stuff": {
        "foo": {
            "name": "Foo"
        },
        "bar": {
            "name": "Bar"
        },
        "baz": {
            "name": "Baz"
        },
        "qux": {
            "name": "Qux"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get all the **.stuff.name**s for **.mine**?

For example, desired output:

```
[
    "Baz",
    "Foo"
]
```

Comment: I am not sure what to try.

Comment: I had to first pull the array .mine into a bash variable and then iterate that variable. I was wondering if it could be done all within jq or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a simple `jq` filter and no other shell processing, do it as below.

```
jq '[.mine[] as $in | .stuff[$in].name]'
```

The logic is basically index the values from `.mine` and for each entry get the equivalent `.name` value in `.stuff`

[jqplay - URL](https://jqplay.org/s/LRHW9BaX42)

Answer (score -1):

Solution. I have saved the file in /tmp/1:

```
cat /tmp/1 | jq "[ .stuff | $(cat /tmp/1 | jq -r '.mine[]' | sed 's/^/./;s/$/.name/;' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//') ]"
```

First i get the names in `.mine[]`, ie `foo` and `baz`. Then i convert them into `.foo.name, .baz.name` and pass to jq `[ .stuff | $(...) ]`, which results in `[ .stuff | .foo.name, .baz.name ]`.